# Period of one oscillation of a PWM signal at 4Mhz and a counter

Tags: pwm

Say I have a counter that increments with a 4MHz clock. Would the period of a single oscillation of the PWM signal be: $${1\over{4\times{10^6}}}=2.5\times10^{-7}s$$

The reason I ask this is because of the context. I haven't had any other questions like this before and I can't find anything about it in my textbook.

I think this is correct since I would assume it would be very small (which the period is).

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: No of course not. To set the duty cycle of a PWM waveform you need clock cycles to set the mark and clock cycles to set the space. More clock cycles means more accurate resolution.

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry, that doesn't really help me here. Are you saying something to the effect that is half the period to get the period of the PWM signal. That is probably really dumb but I'm lost.

Comment: Think about the time resolution that a 4 MHz clock gives you.

Comment: @Andyaka Just so you know, I'm a complete beginner. I didn't know the term "time resolution" so I looked it up and can't see how it relates here. Also, the period I found is the actual "Pulse width" correct? There is a tick every amount of time that I calculated, isn't that the answer to the question I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PWM period is the clock period (\$2.5×10^{-7}=250\text{ ns}\$) multiplied by \$2^n\$, where \$n\$ is the number of bits resolution.

A 16-bit PWM with a 4MHz clock would have a period of 16.384ms.